# How to recover the list of the files from a broken disk

Tags: data-recovery

Hi i'm asking this here because I need to do this on ubuntu, but I think I may be the same for other linux. Recently one of my disk broke, probably the warranty will change, but surely I will loose all my files. Since that moment the computer is off. What I want to do is to recover the list of the files that were on that disk. Is there a way to do this? So i can re download what i can?

Comment: Would you please tell us more what 'broken' means? Is it physically damaged, does the disk not spin, what else?

Comment: Install the program `testdisk` and use it to recover as much data as possible.

Comment: For all purpose is physically broken. I was hoping that in the system there was some kind of cache where i can read what was lost.

Comment: "Is there a way to do this?" Only if the disk can be powered on and is listed by `dmesg`.

Comment: No can do, now I am researching the posibility to use the locate database to rebuild the directory tree.

Comment: If the disk isn't recognized, regardless of the reason, no software will work. Do not waste your time.

Comment: Using the locate database from the system I obtained a list of all my files, Including the files that were on the damaged disk. Now I have to clean the file so I have a clean list.

Answer (score 0):

Finally use the command `strings mlocate.db` and I obtained the complete list of files and folders of the system. After that I copy the part that i need and order manually.